# Footer element keeps shrink in Django templates

Tags: python, html, css, django

I have included the bootstrap footer in to my django base template (base.html) along with pagination.

When I run the django server the footer appear shrink towards the left(  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XyKN.png), then when clicks on the pagination, the footer appear normal with full width ().

Base.html

```
{% load static%}
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>{% block head_title %} Blog {% endblock head_title %}</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href='{%static "css/base.css"%}'>
            <style>
                {% block style %}

                     #main_nav {

                         background-color: white;
                         box-shadow: 5px 10px 20px -20px rgba(85, 172, 238, 1);
                         margin-left: auto;
                         margin-right: auto;
                     }

                     .navbar-toggler {
                         color: #1c2331;
                     }

                     #Create_Post {
                         border-radius: 22.5px;
                         background-color: #ffffff;
                         border-color: black;
                         border-width: 2px;
                     }

                     #Create_Post:hover {
                         border-color: #007bff;
                     }

                     #tag_button {
                         border-radius: 22.5px;
                         background-color: #ffffff;
                         border-color: black;
                         border-width: 2px;
                     }

                     #tag_button:hover {
                         border-color: #007bff;
                     }

                     #no_results {

                         margin-left: auto;
                         margin-right: auto;
                     }

                     #pagination {
                         margin-left: auto;
                         margin-right: auto;

                     }

                     #pagination-link {

                         font-size: 15px;
                         padding: 6px 9px;
                         margin-right: 6px;
                         margin-left: 6px;
                         -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
                         -moz-border-radius: 50%;
                         border-radius: 50%;
                         width: 50px;
                         height: 50px;
                         border-style: solid;
                         border-color: black;
                         border-width: 2px;
                         color: black;
                         text-decoration: none;

                     }

                     #pagination-link:hover {

                         border-color: #007bff;
                         color: #007bff;

                     }
                    #main_footer{
                    background: linear-gradient(135deg,#2a99ef 20%,#52d9e5 80%);
                    width:1287px;
                    }


            {% endblock style %}
            </style>

            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">

        </head>
        <body>
        <header>
        <nav class="navbar  navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top" id="main_nav">

            <div class="col-sm-1"></div>

            <div class="col-sm-2" id="brand">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Full width</a>
            </div>


            <div class="col-12 col-md-6" id="main_search">
            <div id="custom-search-input">
              <form method="GET" action="{% url "posts:search"  %}">
                                    <div class="input-group col-md-12">
                                        <input type="text" class="search-query form-control" placeholder="Search" name="q" />

                                    </div>
              </form>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-2" id="main_links">
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                     <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>


                 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                          <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                              </li>
                          <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                          </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login</a>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
        </nav>
        </header>
        </br>
        </br>
        </br>

        {% include "message_display.html" %}

        <div class="container">

            {% block content %}


            {% endblock %}

        </div>





    <!--Footer-->
    <footer class="page-footer font-small blue pt-4">

      <!-- Footer Links -->
      <div class="container-fluid text-center text-md-left">

        <!-- Grid row -->
        <div class="row">

          <!-- Grid column -->
          <div class="col-md-6 mt-md-0 mt-3">

            <!-- Content -->
            <h5 class="text-uppercase">Footer Content</h5>
            <p>Here you can use rows and columns to organize your footer content.</p>

          </div>
          <!-- Grid column -->

          <hr class="clearfix w-100 d-md-none pb-3">

          <!-- Grid column -->
          <div class="col-md-3 mb-md-0 mb-3">

            <!-- Links -->
            <h5 class="text-uppercase">Links</h5>

            <ul class="list-unstyled">
              <li>
                <a href="#!">Link 1</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#!">Link 2</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#!">Link 3</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#!">Link 4</a>
              </li>
            </ul>

          </div>
          <!-- Grid column -->

          <!-- Grid column -->
          <div class="col-md-3 mb-md-0 mb-3">

            <!-- Links -->
            <h5 class="text-uppercase">Links</h5>

            <ul class="list-unstyled">
              <li>
                <a href="#!">Link 1</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#!">Link 2</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#!">Link 3</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#!">Link 4</a>
              </li>
            </ul>

          </div>
          <!-- Grid column -->

        </div>
        <!-- Grid row -->

      </div>
      <!-- Footer Links -->

      <!-- Copyright -->
      <div class="footer-copyright text-center py-3">© 2020 Copyright:
        <a href="https://mdbootstrap.com/education/bootstrap/"> MDBootstrap.com</a>
      </div>
      <!-- Copyright -->

    </footer>
    <!--/.Footer-->

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/marked/0.3.6/marked.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".post-details").each(function (){
                    var content = $(this).text()
                    console.log(content)
                    var markedContent = marked(content)
                    console.log(markedContent)
                    $(this).html(markedContent)

                })
            })

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Can you please share any link so that I can check this issue ? It will help. Just have a query, have you added Bootstrap CDN to your page as I can see few bootstrap classes in your code.

Comment: Hi @HimanshuJoshi  - Please refer to the attched github link [https://github.com/sithija/blogapp]

Answer (score 0):

Remove the container-div wrapping the content block ({% block content %} ).
If this don't resolve your issue then make sure you're closing all tags properly in the template in which the footer is shrinking.

I faced similar problem, I first wrapped footer tag into a fluid-container(redundant as footer by default spans fluidly.)

The main issue in my case that last div tag was not closed.

If your issue persists then please add code for the template in which footer is shrinking.

Happy Developing :)